# How do I fix how my Titanium Developer app Label is rendering on a TableView?

Tags: javascript, android, appcelerator-mobile

I am having trouble getting the following code to render as I expect it to:

```
var img = Titanium.UI.createImageView({
  top: 0,
  left: 0,
  width: 140,
  height: 92,
  image: 'http://cdn.monmotors.com/tn_' + imgr,
  defaultImage: 'car.png'
});

post_view.add(img);

var lbl = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
  text: desc,
  left: 160,
  width: 'auto',
  top: 0,
  height: 92,
  textAlign: 'left',
  color: '#ffffff',
  font: {
    fontSize: 12,
    fontWeight: 'bold'
  },
});

post_view.add(lbl);
```

This is how it is rendering:

[image: Android Screenshot]

I've set top: 0 and I assumed this would put the label at the top, but this is obviously not the case.

Anyone have any idea how I can achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all the images are the same height, you can set `top` to a negative value (perhaps -92 if your `height` for the image is set to 92).  However, if the image sizes vary, you will likely need to vary the value appropriately.

Ideally, setting `layout: horizontal` in a view you use to wrap the label and the image together would make it so that `top: 0` would work for you, but it appears that [horizontal may not be supported (yet, at least) for Android in Appcelerator](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/42101/horizontal-layout-for-android).  That info is 9 months old, [this link from three weeks ago says that it's now supported](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/116903/android-horizontal-layout), so it's probably worth giving it a shot.

Comment: Where were you in October? :P

Answer (score 1):

top: -70(or other -#) should bring it up